# Completely disable hardware and software buttons

Tags: applications, security

I want to completely disable the three on-screen buttons (Back, Home, Recents) and any other hardware button. I am aware that I cannot do this from the application since that would be a major security flaw. How would I do this to a device assuming that I have the device on hand? Gain root access and then how would this go?

Ps: What I am trying to do is to have the app run on my tablet on a kiosk and I do not want the users to pressing any buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Full!screen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.tsorn.FullScreen&hl=en) has a (paid-for) feature where you can automatically hide system bars in certain apps and unhide them in other apps, but there is a free version without the automation.

Alternatively, you can hide them completely over ADB ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713845/permanently-hide-navigation-bar-on-activity)) with:

```
adb shell
su
pm disable com.android.systemui
```

Or (if you're writing your own app) you can use this code ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713845/permanently-hide-navigation-bar-on-activity)):

```
private void hideNavigationBar(){
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
            os.writeBytes("pm disable com.android.systemui\n");
            os.flush();
            os.writeBytes("exit\n");
            os.flush();
            process.waitFor();
            //////////////////////////////////////
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

[Kiosk Browser Lockdown](http://www.android-kiosk.com/) also has a feature where you can disable all system dialogs (volume, long-press power etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Xposed Framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) and [Xposed Additions](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.spazedog.xposed.additionsgb) you can remap any button to any action, and in your case the 'No action'.

Combining this to disable all your hardware buttons with [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/111625/96277),  and you would achieve what you want.

Open the app and follow these steps:

1. Click on **Buttons**
2. Click **Add new Key**
3. Press the key you want to disable
4. Press **OK**
5. Click the key in the list and for every condition assign the **Disabled** action